# Materialize CSS Panel Images

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm making my own portfolio using `materialize CSS` framework and is having some issues. I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

[image]

As you can see, the images are properly aligned along with the captions below them, and what I have accomplished so far is this:

[image]

How can I possibly do that with materialize css? You can check out the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/uj0ykqpq/1/

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Check this: first all your image files have the same size if they don't have it. You could edit the files or set their container width and height to the desired size. Second CSS for the images includes height: auto; width: 100%;  I will get back to this question when I get to my laptop. Hehe now in a bus. Hope you get a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a fixed height for the images and to align the captions, use `text-align: center` I have added a new class so that it doesn't affect other images in card panels.

```
.technologies .col img {
    height: 100px;
}
.technologies .col {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**Updated JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/j5z130mx/)

Comment: Awesomesauce dude! Works pretty fine.